# Unable to get environment variable values while executing script on remote server

Tags: unix

I m working on hp Unix box. I m trying to execute remote script through ssh.
My target script uses environment variables value internally.
When i do manually ssh and do echo $(env_vairable_name), it prints the value.
But when i execute script remotely, it does not get env variable value.
I m trying blow command to execute remote script.
ssh remote_user@remote_hostname "~/my_script_on_remote.ksh".
Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us at least a portion of your script ?

Comment: This is how i m assigning value:

db_user=$ASMM_INSTALL_DB_USER
db_pwd=$ASMM_INSTALL_DB_PASSWORD
db_instance=$ASMM_INSTALL_DB_INSTANCE

And here i m using them
set -A res `sqlplus -s $db_user/$db_pwd@$db_instance <<ENDOFSQL

Answer (score 1):

You should set the environment variables in the startup file for the Korn shell on the remote host.

You can also use the file `~/.ssh/environment`, but `ssh(1)` warns (emphasis added):

> Additionally, `ssh` reads `~/.ssh/environment`, and adds lines of the format
>   “`VARNAME=value`” to the environment **if** the file exists and **users are
>   allowed to change their environment**.  For more information, see the
>   `PermitUserEnvironment` option in `sshd_config(5)`.

Finally, you can change the script to take command-line arguments instead of read its parameters from the environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse..

~/.ssh/environment did not work, finally i passed arguments.
But now i am facing another problem.My script is trying to connect sqlplus. Though all paramerets are correct, it throwing below error message
ERROR: The SQL Plus command execution failed! Error code: 1
On remote script i m using set -A res `sqlplus -s $db_user/$db_pwd@$db_instance <<ENDOFSQL command to connect.
Any idea why i m getting this error.
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an error message from the SQL Plus command itself; and a cryptic one, too. I've no idea what that command even is, so I can't help you out.